# Trouble with ng-disabled and ng-class

Tags: angularjs

Having trouble making ng-disabled and ng-class work properly.

**ng-disabled**

A variable on the scope tracks how many rows have been selected on a table, and contains a list of rows ids. The button should be disabled when the $scope.selected list is empty.

{{selected}} will show [27982,27983,27984]

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="scope.selected"
        ng-disabled="" ng-click="invokeSaleModal()">Purchase</button>
```

**ng-class**

$scope.purchase.paid is a boolean, holding either **true** or **false**. I am trying to apply the Bootstrap text classes to make the line green or red. Nothing seems to work, even though the **purchase.paid** variable is correct.

```
 <h4 ng-model="purchase.paid" ng-class="{true: success, false: danger}">
     {{purchase.card_message}}
 </h4>
```

EDIT

I tried changing the tag from **h4** to a 



 but no luck. Here is the modified code

```
<p ng-class="{true: 'success', false: 'danger'}[purchase.paid]">
   {{purchase.card_message}} - {{purchase.paid}}
<p>
```

Which displays this

```
Purchase successful - true
```

EDIT2

Thank you to @Josep It turns out I was using the wrong Bootstrap CSS class names.

```
<p ng-class="{true: 'text-success', false: 'text-danger'}[purchase.paid]">
   {{purchase.card_message}} - {{purchase.paid}}
<p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
   ng-disabled="selected.length==0" 
   ng-click="invokeSaleModal()">Purchase</button>
```

#### [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<h4 ng-class="{true: 'success', false: 'danger'}[purchase.paid]">
    {{purchase.card_message}}
</h4>
```

### Update

Since it seems that the OP is having some issues making the `ng-class` work, I've made **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyyecf3/)**

Comment: Thank you @Josep. The ng-disabled works perfectly ... no luck on the ng-class. I will add an edit to the question with more information.

Comment: @ardochhigh hey! no problem, but the `ng-class` code that I gave you should work, [have a look at this example that I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyyecf3/)

Comment: Thank you!! I found the issue: I was using the wrong css classes. See edit2.